# Struts2 tiles advanced appearance

Tags: html, css, struts2, tiles, radix

I have a struts2 web application with tiles.

I need to make header, sidebar and footer as static, ie. stay constant at their position on screen.

An internal scroll bar for body part is needed.

In total I want to create pages with static header, sidebar and footer and content(body) part only moving with the help of an internal scroll bar.

Comment: Which keyword? You need to use CSS/HTML to lay out your page. Tiles aggregates content, it doesn't design it for you.

Comment: Keyword for bringing the sidebar from top in the box instead of middle

Comment: For alligning that side bar on top I found an HTML code valign="top" . Now it is working..
Sorry for disturbing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiles is basically a view layer framework based on `Composite View design pattern`.Purpose of this pattern is to separate pages into reusable pieces so that we can combine them as per the layout.

So your requirement is more towards designing which is case of `CSS/HTML`.Tiles will only help to combine your different pieces together and come up with an aggregation any HTML/CSS changes you have to do in respected HTML piece.

Answer (score 0):

Now I feel it as s silly question. Anyway I am adding an answer for it( May be someone else looking for the same).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.header{
    float:none;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#0000FF;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    height:60px;
}
.menu{
    float:left;
    position:fixed;
    width:20%;
    background-color:#0099FF;
    color:#000000;
    text-align:center;
    height:500px;
    margin-top:60px;
}
.body{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    overflow-y:scroll;  
    text-align:center;
    color:#000000;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:60px;
}
.footer{
    float:none;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    color:#333333;
    text-align:center;
    height:20px;
    margin-top:560px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>


<div class="menu">Menu</div>

<div class="body">
      <p>Body</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>

<div class="footer" >Footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Screen shot]